# Issues with FME and the ArcInfo licence

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, fme-form, arcgis-license-manager

I have ArcInfo 10.2.1, Python 2.7 and FME 2013 SP4 installed on my Computer. I want to run a python script I exported from ModelBuilder (where it ran without issues) and imported in FME as shutdown script in another workbench model. While executing I get this message:

> The Esri Product license used by this machine does not include licenses for the 'ArcInfo' licensing level

I already tried the way [specified here](http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000cgTFAAY) but this doesn't help with my problem. Any ideas what the error could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General issues with the licence server caused the problem. After they were fixed, the error message did not turn up again.